# "Феерический" или "фееричный"?

Tags: лексика

"Феерический" или "фееричный"? Которое из двух слов правильно употреблять или они означают разные понятия? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Многие паронимы в русском языке бывает трудно разграничить. так как в одном или нескольких значениях они еще и синонимы. Слова "феерический" или "фееричный" тоже в одном из значений являются синонимами. Вот что написано в словаре паронимов:

ФЕЕРИЧЕСКИЙ//ФЕЕРИЧНЫЙ

ФЕЕРИЧЕСКИЙ. Представляющий собой феерию, относящийся к ней. (Чаще употребляется в словосочетаниях терминологического характера.) Феерическ|ий: ~ий сюжет; ~ое представление; ~ие превращения; ~ий кордебалет. Первые два десятилетия XIX века были закреплением романтического влияния с патриотическим оттенком. Отсюда влечение к чисто сказочным, феерическим сюжетам. Б. Асафьев. Русская музыка.

ФЕЕРИЧНЫЙ. Содержащий элементы фееричности, напоминающий собой феерию. Фееричн|ый: ~ая быстрота, ловкость; ~ые рассуждения. Сквозь деревья фееричным блеском светилась луна.

Примечание. В значении "волшебный, сказочный; необычайный, удивительный" слова феерический и фееричный продолжают оставаться синонимами: феерическое (фееричное) зрелище, феерическая (фееричная) обстановка.

Answer (score 3):

Дополню, что сейчас в сленговой форме слово "фееричный" стало употребляться в ироническом значении и означает нечто очень курьезное.